# Read document form keyword to keyword and split data into array with python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to read a file in python from one keyword to a second keyword.
After that, I would like to split the data into an array by columns.

My data looks something like this:

```
One Two Three
KEYWORD1
124   129  134
245   345  345
356   357  356
356   354  355
KEYWORD2
Four Five Six
```

What my array should look like:

```
array1 = [124, 245, 356, 356]
array2 = [129, 345, 357, 354]
array3 = [134, 345, 356, 355]
```

How would I implement this feature with python?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open the file. Read line by line checking for the first keyword. For every line after that (that does not match the second keyword) split the line into tokens and convert to int. Append to the appropriate arrays.

Comment: Is there any specific pattern between **KEYWORD**s' names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

```
array1 = []
array2 = []
array3 = []
with open("filename", "r") as f:
    while f.readline().strip() != "KEYWORD1":
        pass
    while (line := f.readline().strip()) != "KEYWORD2":
        nums = line.split()
        array1.append(int(nums[0]))
        array2.append(int(nums[1]))
        array3.append(int(nums[2]))
```

---

- We use `f.readline()` to read the lines of the file one by one. As long as the line is different from `KEYWORD1`, we pass.
- As long as the line is different from `KEYWORD2`, we cut the line along the whitespaces, and we add each element in the corresponding list after having converted them into Int.

The advantage is that by doing so, the entire file is not loaded into memory.

---

**Note:**

- `:=` is the [Walrus operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/), used to assign `line` to `f.readline().strip()` within an expression.

Answer (score 0):

First grab the relevant data with a regex: https://regex101.com/r/yMwJ0l/1

Convert the data to whatever format you like

Comment: The disadvantage of doing it like this is that you have to read the entire file into memory (as text) before you can apply the RE. If the only relevant data are near the beginning of a very large file then this isn't the best idea. Of course it's fine for the sample data shown but I wouldn't suggest it as a generic approach

Comment: There is a thing called premature optimization and overloading rookie questions with details for the sake of showing off mad skillz. But granted, it's not the way to start a new datacenter

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another approach:

```
list1, list2, list3 = [], [], []
lol = [list1, list2, list3]
with open('foo.txt') as foo:
    m = map(str.strip, foo)
    while next(m) != 'KEYWORD1':
        pass
    while (line := next(m)) != 'KEYWORD2':
        for v, a in zip(line.split(), lol):
            a.append(int(v))
for lst in lol:
    print(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[124, 245, 356, 356]
[129, 345, 357, 354]
[134, 345, 356, 355]
```